# How to filter the HERE API V7 reversegeocode api to by resulttype?

Tags: here-api, reverse-geocoding

I am applying the migration of HERE geocoder API from v6 to v7.
My requirement is to fetch the available cities around the selected address by radius.
In v6 I have achieved this by using the below object:
geocoder.reverseGeocode(
{
level: 'city',
mode: 'retrieveAreas',
prox: '36.7783,119.4179,1000',
gen: 9,
maxresults: 50,
jsonattributes: 1,
},
onSuccessFetchCity,
onError
)

In v7 after reading the migration document I have changed the object like below:
platform.getSearchService().reverseGeocode(
{
level: 'city',
mode: 'retrieveAreas',
in: 'circle:36.7783,119.4179;r=1000',
gen: 9,
limit: 50,
jsonattributes: 1,
},
onSuccessFetchCity,
console.error
)

but **level: city** is not working, currently, I am getting all types of addresses into result.
Can anyone help me out on this?

Answer (score 0):

Please note HERE geocoder API v7 is yet to release officially in China Specific regions. Only beta version is now available for use.

For more information kindly refer https://developer.here.com/cn/documentation/geocoder/topics/includes.html